# Is it possible to save the in picture translation as picture?

Tags: ios

When using the app google translate on phone I noticed that it shows the translation of an image inside the image but in the history its just plain text without an image. Is there any way to save the translated image with the text applied in image?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no button to save the translated image with the text applied on the image. The only way is to pause the translation and take a screenshot.

Comment: @Lulucmy I FEARED that. that is the variant i do BUT half of the screen has the menu for the translation then :/ and iphone screens are not THAT huge there ^^'

Answer (score 1):

You can save the translated image with the text applied on it when using google translate on your desktop!

There will be a button to ‘Download Translation’, which will save the images with translation overlays to your computer :)

Answer (score 0):

Share your Google lens translated image with a photo editing app.

Translated with **Google** lens will be underneath the image

[image]

[image]